# Google Nearby Notifications suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I have been working on Eddystone Nearby Notifications for a little over two months now. I have more than 10 beacons and they were all working until now. Even though the beacon dashboard.

For debugging this I tried using the beacons on an other Google account and they worked. I then tried on an other project on the same account that has the problem and they worked. I finally put them back on my production project and they stopped working again.

I removed all notifications from the beacons except for one and that didn't fix it either.

I do however see the notifications in settings->google->nearby.

I'm wondering why this is happening and what gotchas are there revolving around this?

Thank you!

PS: I'm also using the api so that my users may publish attachments to their beacons. That also used to work.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same happened with me! I tried everything, increasing the API quota, deleting and adding the beacon, even contacting Google cloud support about it. 
It seems they do not support Proximity API, and there doesn't seem to be any way of knowing as to why that would happen. 
The notifications wouldn't show in the drawer, but would show up in Nearby app. I am guessing Google were working on a fix while doing that.
(I have build a beacon management platform too, but it scares me that this might happen again)

Comment: Thanks for your input, super useful. Lets look into this as much as we can and maybe build a group of people that have this problem because having this happen when we have 1000s of beacons will be a disaster.

Comment: Yes I would still like to figure out as to why that happened. Google doesn't seem to have anything laid out for that.
(on a side note how do I keep in touch with you?)